# Do you know a survey of modular Lie algebras and its representations?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, modular-representation-theory, modular-lie-algebras

When I was an university student, I liked reading some books about the representation theory of finite groups or Lie algebras and I was interested in explicit constructions of irreducible representations of these algebraic objects.

As a hobby, I bought and read Strade-Farnsteiner(1988), but I didn't know current survey of these areas. Do you know some applications or connections of representation theory of modular Lie algebras to the other subjects?

As possible as I know, I like the Zassenhaus's results that explains a connection between irreducible representations of restricted Lie algebras and some affine algebraic varieties). It is very beautiful:)

Comment: Humphreys has a book [Modular representations of finite groups of Lie type](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511525940).  It's not my speciality, so I can't speak directly to it, but usually an exposition by Humphreys is a good place to start.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for replying! I am interested in this direction of applications because the root systems or Dynkin diagrams which determine the structure of finite dimensional complex or modular classical simple Lie algebras are active in these areas and give many combinatorial aspects. Such symmetric objects are very beautiful but finite dimensional modular simple Lie algebras contain non-classical type called Cartan type which is not match valid in this way. Nevertheless they are same "simple Lie algebras":( Is there an unified way these modular Lie algebras? Any way, I like this areas:)

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1198126), I see here and from your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1198122) on @MatthieuRomagny's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461806) that you are specifically interested in phenomena that don't, in some sense, "come from a Lie group"—which is so exactly orthogonal to my expertise that unfortunately I can't say anything useful.  Strade does have a recent (2000's) book series called "Simple Lie algebras over fields of positive characteristic", but I haven't read it, so I couldn't say how useful it is for what you need.

Answer (score 6):

Jens Carsten Jantzen has two surveys which, although not the most up-to-date, are very relevant still:

1. Representations of Lie algebras in prime characteristic, in Broer, A. (ed.) et al., Representation theories and algebraic geometry. Proceedings of the NATO Advanced Study Institute, Montreal, Canada, July 28-August 8, 1997. Kluwer, 1998.
2. Representations of Lie algebras in positive characteristics, in Shoji, Toshiaki (ed.) et al., Representation theory of algebraic groups and quantum groups. Advanced Studies in Pure Mathematics 40, 175-218 (2004).

Comment: Thank you for replying! To be honest, I knew above survey papers. I feel that these papers deal with the representation theory of reductive algebraic groups rather than Lie algebras, in contrast the aspect like "Lie algebras of algebraic groups" has many rich properties and applications. For example, diagrams of linkage principle are so nice:)